# What can Boost do that modern C++'s standard library cannot? What is the need of including boost as a dependency in a program?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++17, std

Considering latest modern C++, so C++17, are there any features that Boost has that are not available in C++17 standard library?

In other words: is there anything you cannot accomplish (with a reasonable solution) with modern C++(standard library) for which you need to include Boost as a dependency in your project?

Can you please provide a list of such features, that are in Boost and NOT in modern C++17(standard library)?

And what about C++11 and C++14?

Comment: I don't get the question.  Boost is written in C++ so anything it does you can do yourself.

Comment: Are you asking whether there are any Boost libraries that have not been incorporated into the standard library in C++11 through C++17? (Yes, most of them have not been.)

Comment: boost can provide a platform for library code that is still too experimental/controversial to be considered to be standardized, basically thats what boost was made for

Comment: yes but, for example, before modern C++ there were many things pretty hard to implement yourself and it made much more sense to just use Boost. Now with modern C++ you have many more features that deprecate some of the Boost features. I was wondering if it is reasonable in 2019 to add Boost as a dependency of your project or if sticking with modern standard C++ features is enough

Comment: So opinion based... And so broad...

Comment: *I was wondering if it is reasonable in 2019 to add Boost as a dependency of your project or if sticking with modern standard C++ features is enough* It depends on what you need.  If you need a tuple there is no reason.  If you need a map with both the key and value acting as keys then you should just include bimap since it's already been implemented.

Comment: Unfortunately, opinion-based or too broad is off topic on SO.

Comment: SMH at people marking this question "opinion-based": it's certainly possible to enumerate through the features that boost provides that aren't part of the C++ STL without getting into "opinion" territory. Don't mark questions off-topic just because *you* don't want to answer them!

Comment: why this was closed as "opinion-based"? How presence of some feature in standard library is an opinion not a fact?

Comment: @MarekR the question originally was just *"is there anything you cannot accomplish (with a reasonable solution) with modern C++ for which you need to include Boost as a dependency in your project?"* which is a vague question considering Boost is written in C++.

Comment: @Ayxan IMO people are picking on unimportant detail/words. With this thinking why do you need standard library? After all C++ is compete Turing machine so you can do anything.

Comment: Yes I can see this one going through a few open / close cycles. I've asked the @mods to intervene.

Comment: Question is temporarily locked to stop the yoyo attention. For those feeling strongly enough when the lock is removed, it can be re-closed.

Comment: I have closed this for now as I agree that this question is too broad, and also not a good fit as any answer would be outdated on a regular basis. If someone disagrees with my judgment here, I would suggest they post a question on Meta instead of engaging in close and reopen wars.

Answer (score 6):

Boost has a wide variety of libraries most of which haven't been incorporated into the standard library. They include but are not limited to:

- Networking and other inter process communication
- Linear algebra
- Serialisation
- Parsing
- Signals & Slots
- much more...

Furthermore, using Boost for features that are in 
C++17 gives you some compatibility to older compilers.

Answer (score 4):

Date libraries (over which there would be too much of a disagreement to be in the C++ standard - look at the mess in Java), Boost Spirit, multiprecision, and linear algebra libraries are things that are not in the C++ standard.

Plus a definition of *pi* (although we finally get one of those in C++20).

Because many feature in Boost eventually make themselves into the standard (`std::regex`, `std::unique_ptr`, `std::thread`, `std::unordered_map`) with minimal changes, Boost is well-worth sticking with.

Comment: C++20 is getting a date library.

Comment: Actually, a [date library by Howard Hinnant](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/d0355r7.html) was voted into the draft for C++20 (so although it doesn't have one quite yet, it soon will).

Comment: Would you like a date?

Comment: boost asio  - network API
boost beast - network protocols http websocket

Comment: @SombreroChicken; I thought you'd never ask. What kind of duration?

Comment: And linear algebra might appear for C++23. Or not.

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<Bathsheba>::infinity()`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I'll take a look. It would need to support things like leap seconds (none of that Google smear nonsense) and ideally transitions from Julian to Gregorian to keep the historians happy.

Comment: Wait, so Bathsheba has a floating point? I'd never have guessed...

Comment: @Bathsheba: It includes: "Several <chrono> clocks for computing with leap seconds which is also supported by the IANA Time Zone Database." I'm less certain about Julian calendar support. That's tougher to do, since the date of transition from Julian to Gregorian varies widely (anywhere from 15th century in Catholic European countries to sometime in the future--if ever--for Orthodox Catholic churches, among others).

Comment: C++20 has [proleptic Gregorian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar) support built-in.  And it supports user-written calendars that it will interoperate with.  One could write a Julian calendar which will convert to and from the chrono Gregorian calendar for _any_ date, thus sidestepping the fact that different countries switched at different times.  [Here is a working proof of concept of such a Julian calendar.](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/julian.html)

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Yes the contribution you have made to C++20 is outstanding. Out of interest, did we get leap seconds supported?

Comment: Yes. [`utc_clock`](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.utc) supports leap seconds.  And one can convert `time_points` among `system_clock` and `utc_clock` (as well as several other new clocks:  `file_clock`, `tai_clock`, `gps_clock`).